# When and why does the "brittleness" of mutual information cause overfitting?

Tags: terminology, entropy, mutual-information, overfitting

I have frequently heard concern over "brittleness" of entropy and mutual information as performance metrics for a statistical fitting and the fact that it leads to overfitting. You can see an example of such concern [in this blog post](http://hunch.net/?p=22). However I have trouble understanding what exactly "brittleness" means in this context, and in which cases it would be a basis for overfitting.

- In which cases should entropy and mutual information not be used?
- If they are used, how can you ensure that no overfitting occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what does "brittle" mean in statistics, but in case it looks like "Traditional overfitting" - with too few data points it is easy to max mutual information, even though there is no dependence between variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Piotr. Just to make sure: you mean that in case we have too few datapoints with a lot of features, it is easy to find identical features for those of them and attribute a maximal informativeness to those features, even if in fact they are completely random. What would be a good way of avoiding such overfitting or at least verifying for it?

Comment: In general, mutual information needs some data (often more than other methods). If you see counts 1 or 2 appearing often, it means that mutual information will overfit. The only way to deal with it is to bin some data (e.g. if you have values of one variable `1`,`2`,`3` and `4` then you can use instead `[1,2]` and `[3,4]`).